# Converting an integer to datetime and comparing the date in c#

Tags: c#

I am having an issue in parsing two integers to datetime in C#. I have two integers as follows:

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08; 
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";
```

What I want is to convert `day, month and the current year` to format `dd/MM/yyyy` and compare this date to scheduledDate which is in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy`. Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: You can just concatenate them `var date = $"{day}/{month}/{currentYear}"`

Comment: I want to preserve any preceding 0 before day or month.

Comment: forget about a specific format, and leading zeroes etc. Just create a Date object with the correct date and compare it to another Date object. Formats such as dd/mm/yyyy are strictly for display purposes only. When you actually want to process or calculate a date or time you use Date or DateTime objects, which don't use any specific format. When you want to display a date or time to the user, only then do you worry about the format.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than converting `DateTime` object to `String` you should always convert `String` to `DateTime` object and then compare it.

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08; 
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";
var dtScheduledDate = DateTime.ParseExact(scheduledDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dtCurrentDate = new DateTime(currentYear, month, day);

if (dtScheduledDate < dtCurrentDate)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourDateTime = new DateTime(currentYear, month, day);
var yourDateString = yourDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
// compare
```

Comment: Why convert `DateTime` object to string, instead of converting `string` to `DateTime`?

Comment: @SeM: Guy said he wanted to compare strings so it does it, nothing more, nothing less

Comment: You always have choice to show someone a "right" (whatever that means) way to do something.

Comment: @SeM: You don't know what he wanted exactly, I didn't see the whole code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare only date then you can use `Date` Property of `DateTime`

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08; 
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

var dateToCompare = new DateTime(currentYear, month, day);

var scheduledDt = "25/08/2018";
var scheduledDate = DateTime.ParseExact(scheduledDt, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if(dateToCompare.Date == scheduledDate.Date)
{
    //Your logic
}
```

POC: [.Net Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEP1iV)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, you could use [DateTime.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) method to convert it into the [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) you need.

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08;
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day);
var formattedDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";

// Compare formattedDate and scheduledDate
```

**OR**

You could consider converting the scheduledDate string to date time and compare the date time objects, if that's more appropriate:

```
var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(scheduledDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day);

// compare date & parsed date
bool areEqual = date.Equals(parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, just keep the proceeding zero,

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08;
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;            
var targetDate = $"{day}/{month.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0')}/{currentYear}";
var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";
var difference = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(targetDate), 
DateTime.Parse(scheduledDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to convert it to a string, this should be the easiest way:

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08;
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

// {day:D2} is equivalent to day.ToString("D2") which pads integers to a length of two
var createdDate = $"{day:D2}/{month:D2}/{currentYear}";

var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";
```

**EDIT**
Picking up on a few things people here said, parsing both to a `DateTime` might be more suitable for the comparing part:

```
DateTime createdDateTime = new DateTime(currentYear, month, day);

DateTime scheduledDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(scheduledDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Compare if it's the same day
if (createdDateTime.Date == scheduledDateTime.Date)
{
    // do stuff
}

// Get the difference in Days
int dayDifference = (createdDateTime - scheduledDateTime).Days;
```

Alternatively `.TotalDays` instead of `.Days` returns a `double`

Answer (score 0):

```
int day = 25;
int month = 08; 
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";

// parse string into DateTime structure
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-UK");
var dtScheduledDate = DateTime.Parse(scheduledDate, ci);

var dtOther = new DateTime(currentYear, month, day);

if(dtOther > dtScheduledDate)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case if your variable `scheduleDate` is a string you can convert the other variables `(day,month and currentYear)` into a string in the format you want:

```
var dt = day + "/" + month  + "/" + currentYear;
```

So to compare you do this:

```
if(dt.Equals(scheduleDate))
 //Do some
else
 //other thing
```

Comment: comparing strings is a bad way to compare dates.

Comment: I understand Mr. ADyson. I gave this solution course i could see that the other variable we wants to compare to is a string (var scheduledDate = "25/08/2018";)

Comment: True, but actually OP didn't say what kind of comparison they want. If they want simple equals, then a string comparison will do the job, assuming the exact same format is used in both cases. However if they wanted to do less than / greater than, then for dates a string comparison will not work as desired (especially in a format like dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int transactionDate = 20201010;
    int? transactionTime = 210000;

    var agreementDate = DateTime.Today;
    var previousDate = agreementDate.AddDays(-1);

    var agreementHour = 22;
    var agreementMinute = 0;
    var agreementSecond = 0;

    var startDate = new DateTime(previousDate.Year, previousDate.Month, previousDate.Day, agreementHour, agreementMinute, agreementSecond);
    var endDate = new DateTime(agreementDate.Year, agreementDate.Month, agreementDate.Day, agreementHour, agreementMinute, agreementSecond);

    DateTime selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(transactionDate.ToString().Substring(6, 2) + "/" + transactionDate.ToString().Substring(4, 2) + "/" + transactionDate.ToString().Substring(0, 4) + " " + string.Format("{0:00:00:00}", transactionTime));

    Console.WriteLine("Selected Date : " + selectedDate.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Start Date : " + startDate.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("End Date : " + endDate.ToString());

    if (selectedDate > startDate && selectedDate <= endDate)
        Console.WriteLine("Between two dates..");
    else if (selectedDate <= startDate)
        Console.WriteLine("Less than or equal to the start date!");
    else if (selectedDate > endDate)
        Console.WriteLine("Greater than end date!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Out of date ranges!");
}
```

Output:
Selected Date : 10.10.2020 21:00:00
Start Date : 8.10.2020 22:00:00
End Date : 9.10.2020 22:00:00
Greater than end date!